# jQuery functions: why is the completion of the first event delayed until a second event finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, timing

This has been bugging me for ages, and so I've created a test [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pbgz3/1/) to illustrate the situation.

The code is as follows:

```
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'red');
    for (var i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = "Another";
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(el);
    }
});
```

Now, I would have thought that the background color should change first, and then the creation of the children would begin. The color doesn't change, though, until after the `for` loop has finished.

This is not the case, however, if you put a `setTimeout` delay in place of the `for` loop.

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('#test').css('background', 'blue');
}, 2000);
```

In the `setTimeout` case, you see instantaneous red and then blue 2 seconds later. EDIT: Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWBNQ/) for the second case.

Why does my first fiddle do what it does? It applies in so many other situations, particularly regarding AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser isn't triggering a repaint until the whole of the function has executed.

You can make it repaint before calling the for loop by wrapping the for in a setTimeout with a timeout of zero, like so:

```
$('#test').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css('background', 'red');
  setTimeout(function(){
    for (var i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = "Another";
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(el);
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Pipalayan Nayak's answer works for the same reason.  The call to `alert` is what triggers the repaint.

Answer (score 1):

You only have 1 main thread in javascript.

Loops block everything from happening, things like queued `setTimeouts()` or background repaints.

The difference is, `setTimeout()` doesn't require heavy computations, because it's just a stack, so your 100,000 iterations loops finishes quicker, and allows the next queued function (in this case, the repaint) to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a simple modification of it http://jsfiddle.net/Pbgz3/12/ . The color indeed changes before the loop is run. To check that i have decreased the looping iterations.

Comment: If you remove the alert and increase the iterations again, it still delays the colour change. As @market notes, it's the `alert` that is making it work ('triggering the repaint').